# iPhone Notes become blank/empty in times, you get them back after OS restart

Tags: iphone, bug, notes.app

This is taking up the wording and image of the 201911 Apple forum question [Apple Notes Blank](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250875736).

> Sometimes when I go to my notes on my phone, the contents of my notes have disappeared.

[image]

If you still write or speak in a new note during such a bug, you will not see the text, but the text still gets saved and the note will show up with its first letters in the overview of all notes. If you click on it, it still will be blank. The note saves anything what you wrote or spoke, but without spaces, and after restart, you can work it over. The screenshot below does not show this in full since there is still a space in the first note, but it catches the problem well enough.

[image]

After such a bug, how can I get the notes back without restarting the iPhone?

Other official Apple forum questions that deal with the same thing (searched for "notes often empty and need restart iphone"):

- Another 202010 question for an iPhone 11 shows that it is still there for this higher model, see [iPhone notes vanish often until I restart phone](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251909439).
- 202006 [My iPhone notes keep going blank after updating to iOS 13.1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251513175)
- [My iPhone notes show up blank all of a sudden](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251975575)
- [Same question was asked in the same forum long before 2019 as well, link was removed](https://origin-discussions-us.apple.com/thread/253558865). *This thread was removed only up to four months after asking this question after being out there for many many years... I try not to see a link...* I wanted to write down the year of the question in an edit and must see that the link is dead. I can only guess and vaguely remember that "long before" was something old, could have been 2014-2016 or even earlier. Perhaps it was also just removed for its age.

Wrapping up the links, the problem must have been known for a (very) long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TLDR:

For example, on an iPhone 7, being in the Notes app showing nothing, double tap the home button, swipe up, open Notes again. That is all you need to do to see the writing again, no need to restart the iPhone.

You will sometimes see more than one copy of the note after such an error. Then you can delete any entry but the top one:

[image]

I have checked this many times, the top one is always the youngest note with the most of any text entered at the time of the bug.

Close the notes app as soon as you do not need it anymore if you often run into these blank notes. The blank-notes error only happens if Notes tries to sync while it does not have a connection (my experience of a year).

Thus, if you often have a bad connection or if you have not switched on your internet, close the app as soon as you have entered something, and the bug should never come up. On the other hand, since the bug is so small, you can also risk running into it. I just do not like to delete any notes, even if I am 100 % sure that they are duplicates, since I know myself: one day, I will not think enough and delete a note that was not a duplicate... It takes time to be sure about what you want to delete, and therefore, always closing the app is on the safe side.

---

[The first answer in that forum from 2019 says it already.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250875736?answerId=250875736021#250875736021)

If you run into this bug, you do not need to restart the iPhone. You can just follow the guide at [Close an app on your iPhone or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201330).

That is, just close the app. I forgot that there were so many apps open, you see them when double-tapping the home button (older iPhones) or when swiping up to the middle. And then swipe through the open apps to find the Notes app and close it by swiping it up.

If you open the Notes app again, the notes will be back without a restart.

I guess this problem does not come up with the Apple iCloud Notes since they are synchronized by the device and work fine even if you go from online to offline and back. This synchronization does not seem to work well enough for any other note provider. Thus, my guess, if you lose the internet and still type, you may run into this.

It seems not too far-fetched that this is a bug on the wishlist: "kindly switch to Apple iCloud as the storage for your notes, since the other services are buggy".

Strange: the oldest link (I can only guess the age: half a decade or even more) that is listed above was removed only a few months after this question was put here.